# Primefaces inputMask accept only hex

Tags: javascript, jsf, primefaces, xhtml

I'm facing a terrible problem with the update of primefaces from 6.2.5 to 7.0.4.
Before i was using a `inputMask` like this way:

```
<p:inputMask id="input" value="#{bean.inputs.id}" mask="^^ ^^ ^^ ^^ ^^"
             requiredMessage="#{label.lblRequired}" >
    <f:validator validatorId="Validator"/>
</p:inputMask>
```

there is also an javascript part where i definie the usage of "^"

```
$.mask.definitions['^'] = '[A-Fa-f0-9]';
```

with primefaces 7.0.4 i can't use this pattern anymore as you can see in this commit: [Link to primefaces github](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/commit/d4119edf5aee7ae76f9032786d944782aa72b62d).
Additional if i use this way, there is no error but the value keeps beeing empty but on the webpage it is filled the right way.

My question would be if there is any other way to add a regex to every field of my input? Or is there a pattern that i am missing

What i tried so fare is:

1. add `<f:validateRegex pattern="[regex]"/>` --> no good
2. add `<p:keyFilter regEx="[regex]" />` --> working only on inputText
3. trying to add regex for each "^" --> no good

Comment: How can you determine that particular GitHub commit caused the issue.  If it was working as is now broken why not submit an issue on the PrimeFaces Github Issues page?

Comment: @Melloware cause maybe it's not a bug but a feature and i'm don't know how to use the mask pattern the right way. to ensure that i'm asking on a Q/A platforme for advice, maybe there is someone who had the same problem. that's what stackoverflow is for ;)

Comment: If it is something that worked by luck and shouldn't have or it worked as it should and doesn't anymore, bot are valid reasons to post an issue in the PrimeFaces issuelist.

Comment: @Mofty check if there is something here that affected the inputmask https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/wiki/Migration-Guide

Comment: `id="input"` looks ambiguous. You should avoid using `id` attribute where possible and not "over-id" all things as the `id` is being used internally by JSF/PF engine for building the component tree. Over-usage of it may lead to bugs you cannot explain yourself, until you remove all unneeded `id` attributes. Careful!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are correct that it was broken in PrimeFaces 7.0 with this security fix: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/3234

Comment in that thread from the developer who patched this security hole.

> jquery.maskedinput lets you define your own rules aka mask
>   definitions, e.g. ~ can be defined to be mapped to + or -. Example
>   from https://github.com/digitalBush/jquery.maskedinput

```javascript
jQuery(function($){    
   $.mask.definitions['~']='[+-]';   
   $("#eyescript").mask("~9.99 ~9.99 999"); 
});
```

> However, PrimeFaces does not seem to implement this feature. So I ignored it in my commit.

So it appears you should comment on that bug ticket saying it caused a regression issue.

**Update 9/2/2019**: This has been fixed for PF 7.0.8 and 7.1: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/5105